# Replace if the first two letters are repeating in python

Tags: python, regex

How to replace if the first two letters in a word repeats with the same letter?

For instance,

```
 string = 'hhappy'
```

And I want to get

```
happy
```

I tried with

```
re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', string)
```

But, this gives

```
hapy
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `r'\b(\w)\1+'`

Comment: Great! \b defines the beginning (or end) of the word with any character \w repeating more than once.

Comment: Glad to help. I've added my suggestion as an answer. Feel free to mark it as accepted if it worked for you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a [caret (`^`)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) to match only the start of the line.

```
re.sub(r'^(.)\1+', r'\1', string)
```

Example:

```
import re
string = 'hhappy'
print re.sub(r'^(.)\1+', r'\1', string)
```

Prints:

```
happy
```

---

The above works only for the start of the line. If you need this for each *word* you need to do this:

```
re.sub(r'\b(\w)\1+', r'\1', string)
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex would be

```
\b(\w)\1+
```

`\b` checks for a word boundary.

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bX3xR8/1).

Answer (score 1):

Or you could simply slice:

```
string = 'hhappy'

func = lambda s: s[1:] if s[0] == s[1] else s
new_string = func(string)
# happy
```

Comment: This is probably preferable to using regex because the ease of use and understandability.